# Disable Row in TelerikGrid in XAML Using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, telerik

I am using a `WPF` Application, In that application I am using a telerik gird and also i am using `MVVM` model to bind data in the grid. I want to disable or gray out the rows based on the value in the collection getting bind to the grid. Its a bool value.

Is there anything like setting a property `IsReadOnlyBinding` for column in the below code.

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn Width="40" IsFilterable="False"  HeaderTextAlignment="Center" Header="Max" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Constraint.MaxCountConstraint, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnlyBinding="{Binding MyBoolValue}" Tag="Exclude" />
```

How can i do the same for row?

The grid code is,

```
<telerik:RadGridView x:Name="grdSetup" MinHeight="100" telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Windows8" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding MCCollection, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowGroupPanel="False" RowIndicatorVisibility="Collapsed" >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the IsReadOnlyBinding property of RadGridView - the full row becomes read only when the underlying property is True.

```
<telerik:RadGridView x:Name="radGridView" IsReadOnlyBinding="{Binding IsActive}" />
```